# Is there any way to import an image to my materialui-nextjs project

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I imported the image like this :

```js
import img from '../public/buildingspattern.png'
```

then used it in the component :

```js
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={img}
        title="Buildings"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
          Something
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
```

then I fixed my `next.config.js`

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "fr"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      ],
    })

    return config
  },
};
```

I think I miss something here
The App starts fine, But the image isn`t there.

That's what I see in the webpage after I `yarn dev`

```js
<div class="MuiCardMedia-root 
    makeStyles-media-16" 
    style="background- 
       image:url("8a955c62dc9b08f560cb800b273932ac.png")" 
    title="Buidings">
</div>
```

Comment: try src prop or set hieght to CardMedia

Answer (score 3):

I came across another way as I just implemented it today..
Which is simpler and more efficient,

- Go to the Card component in MaterialUi
- Replace the standard `<img/>` tag with `<Image />` tag
- Also please add `import Image from 'next/image'`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you create a component for returning Image

```
import Image from 'next/image';


function ImageComponent() {
    return (
        <Image src="../public/someImage.png" alt="Buildings Pattern"/>
    );
};
```

And use this component in your image attribute using interpolation as you did above

```
image={ImageComponent}
```

✌

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can use the absolute path of the image in next.js like this `/image-name`, If don't work you will create a directory in the public directory as name `static` and put your image in the static directory then you can access `/static/image name`